# не работает fetch

Tags: javascript, ajax

```
fetch('server.php')
.then(function(response) {
    console.log( response.json());
})
```

не пойму как работает этот фетч

Comment: почему ты думаешь, что `fetch` не работает?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Использование **fetch**
При вызове `fetch` возвращает промис, который, когда получен ответ, выполняет коллбэки с объектом Response или с ошибкой, если запрос не удался.

```
    fetch('/article/fetch/user.json')
  .then(function(response) {
    alert(response.headers.get('Content-Type')); // application/json; charset=utf-8
    alert(response.status); // 200

    return response.json();
  })
  .then(function(user) {
    alert(user.name); // iliakan
  })
  .catch(alert);
```

Объект `response` кроме доступа к заголовкам `headers`, статусу `status` и некоторым другим полям ответа, даёт возможность прочитать его тело, в желаемом формате.

Варианты описаны в спецификации **Body**, они включают в себя:

- `response.arrayBuffer()`
- `response.blob()`
- `response.formData()`
- `response.json()`
- `response.text()`

Соответствующий вызов возвращает промис, который, когда ответ будет получен, вызовет коллбэк с результатом.
В примере выше в первом `.then` анализируем ответ и, если он нас устроит – вернуть промис с нужным форматом. Следующий .`then` уже будет содержать полный ответ сервера.

ка кто так

Answer (score 1):

чуть чуть не правильно используешь, `response.json()` это обещание и надо обрабатывать по другому
 вот немного поправил

```
fetch('server.php')
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(function(data) {
    console.log(data); // тут уже пишем нашу логику обработки
  })
  .catch(alert);
```

Comment: что именно исправил? почему именно так надо?

Comment: потому что response.json() это обещание и надо обрабатывать по другому

Comment: добавь пояснение в сам ответ